# Would the influence of a black hole nearby cause a tilt of 63° of our solar system in relation to our galaxy?

Tags: black-hole, solar-system, axial-tilt

I am trying to understand the influence of black holes and the tilts of solar systems on their axial plane In relation to the plane of their host galaxies.

Comment: No Black hole can create such peterbutions on the axial tilt, only Gravitational anomalies can do this.

Comment: Albeit concentrated but still, isn’t a black hole a gravitational anomaly? I understand if in close proximity to the event horizon  poses a risk of destruction  and consumption completely. At a certain distance and position it seems to me that it could have some influence if not physically possibly our perception of a tilt may be plausible. Gravitational forces do seem to cause  some visual distortions.  Just postulating ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!. Blackhole is'nt a gravitational anomaly. Unless the blackhole is some ultramassive blackhole, though our galaxy is chaotic it wouldn't cause much **visible** difference, Saggitarius A causes less perterbution on the solar system's axial tilt then neighboring stars. Nice thought experiment

Answer (score 2):

Everything I've read indicates that the orientation of a star system with respect to the galactic plane is pretty much random. It depends on the local angular momentum of the gas cloud from which the star system formed, and that local angular momentum is more or less uncorrelated with the angular momentum of the galaxy as a whole. A black hole is not needed.

I'll add references later, perhaps this weekend. I'll delete this answer if someone beats me to the punch with a well-referenced answer that says the same.